# The usage of 'も' in a question

Tags: grammar, usage

I'm really new to learning Japanese, so can answers be kept simple, please.
I just learned about 'も' as far as I am aware, this means 'also' or 'as well', my question concerns its usage in a basic question statement.

私は日本人ですみどりやはも日本人ですか

My understanding is that this means "I am Japanese, is Midoriya also Japanese?"
Since I am using 'も', do I also need to use 'は', or does it replace its declarative function?

私は日本人ですみどりや**は**も日本人ですか

There may be a whole lot more than this that I am cocking up though

Comment: も always replaces は. You never use them together. You also need some full stops. 私は日本人です。みどりやも日本人ですか。It looks really weird if you leave out the first full stop (and some cases could change the meaning of what you write).

Comment: By the way I didn't down vote, but this site expects you to do a little research before you ask a question. There are many online resources for teaching basic Japanese that you should probably have a look at first. See this list for starters: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese

Comment: If your question has been answered, please feel free to click the green check mark next to the answer you'd like to accept.  There's no need to edit the word "answered" into your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

も *replaces* は.

- も replaces は and を. (there is [an exception](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13405/5010), but you can forget it for now)
- も is used in combination with other particles including から, まで, へ, に, etc.

> 私は日本人です。みどりや**も**日本人ですか？